# Get website's html to a textbox

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

I was trying this but keep getting the error that gecko doesn't contain a definition for innerHTML..

```
GeckoElement g2element = null;
g2element = (GeckoElement)mainbrowsersrc.Document.GetElementByTagName("html");
rich1.Text = g2element.InnerHtml; // 48.066
```

or

```
  rich1.Text = mainbrowsersrc.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html").innerHtml;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the HTML of the entire page, then you should go with

```
(mainbrowsersrc.Document.DocumentElement as Gecko.DOM.GeckoHtmlHtmlElement)?.InnerHtml;
```

Please notice that the error that you get is because there is no method `.GetElementByTagName(name);` - the method is called `GetElementsByTagName(name)` - plural form.

This is because the tg name is **not unique** and the method **returns a collection** of elements with the same tag name - for example a collection of `li` (list item) elements.

Consequently, if you want to get a particular element *by tag name*, you should do something like:

```
string html = mainbrowsersrc.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html").FirstOrDefault().innerHtml;
//or 
html = mainbrowsersrc.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHtml;
```